# Get first element with class X after

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup example:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <input name="country"/>
  <span class="message">Fill your country</span>
  <span class="error">Error</span>
</div>
```

The error span can be immediately after the input or not.

Being `element` then country input I have to get the error span:

```
var error = element.parent().children("span.error");
```

This is working but does not feel right ... Is there a better way?

Basically, I need to get the first span.error after 'input.country'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first error span

`element.siblings("span.error:first")`

To get all error spans

`element.siblings("span.error")`

Answer (score 0):

```
var error = element.siblings("span.error:first");
```

Use siblings method.